# How to create a primary association key without being unique

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to create a primary association key but I don't want it to be unique because I have a date column that differentiates the records. Can someone help me?

Comment: A key in a database must by definition be unique. You need to include the date field in a composite key if you want to be able to solve this.

Comment: yes @RogerGustavsson I do it

Comment: A primary key must always be unique. As hibernate follows this rule just as strictly as your database, there is no way to do what you want. There can be no ambiguity as to which records relate to one another

Answer (score 0):

Well. Your primary key must be unique. If it's not unique, it's not a primary key.
If whatever column you're using currently really really CANT be unique for whatever reason, you can:

- Create another field to hold an automatically generated ID, and set THAT as the primary key. You can still search by date, you can even index it. This is the simplest, easiest, best option unless you have some *very* good reason not to do it.
- Create a composite key that includes your date column and what used to be your id column, set that as your primary key if it's even possible.

Remember, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)